# Color in histbackback (in Hmisc package)

Tags: r, colors, histogram

How to color the bars of a back-to-back histogram created with histbackback command (Hmisc package)? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for hmisc?

Comment: Yes, graphical parameters can be added, but I can't find the answer to my question. This is a minimal example: a=rnorm(100,7,1.5)
b=rnorm(100,5,1.5)
histbackback(a,b,probability=F,axes=F)